# Convert a String to Function in java

Tags: java

I want to convert a String into a Function in java (java.util.function.Function).

for example:

```
String stringFunction="a->a+1";

Function<Integer,Integer>function=fromStringToFunction(stringFunction);
```

Can you help me write the method `fromStringToFunction`?

Note: Lambda isn't necessary, just the interface. Could have used instead:

```
Function<Integer,Integer>function=new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer a) {
        return a+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input, the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: I think you can start by trying out Javassist https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you best bet is to evaluate the string to function using Groovy and it [Eval utility, integrated in Java](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/guide-integrating.html), here is an example that works:

```
import groovy.util.Eval;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class EvalStringAsFunc {
    public static Function<Double,Double> fromStringToFunction(String expression) {
        Function<Double,Double> function = x -> (double)Eval.x(x,expression);
        return function;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Double x = 10.0; //example input
        Double y = 0.2; //example input

        // example of 1 parameter (x) function
        String func1 = "x+2";
        double result1 = (double) Eval.x(x,func1);
        System.out.println(result1);
        //prints 12

        // example of 2 parameter (x,y) function
        String func2 = "10*Math.pow(x,2)+2+y";
        double result2 = (double) Eval.xy(x,y,func2);
        System.out.println(result2);
        //prints 1002.2

        //using fromStringToFunction
        String stringFunction="x+1";
        Function<Double,Double>function=fromStringToFunction(stringFunction);
        double result3 = function.apply(7.0);
        System.out.println(result3);
        //prints 8.0

    }
}
```

In order for that to work, you'll need Groovy as a dependency. So if you're using Maven, you should add to your POM file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Felipe already said in his comment, ByteCode manipulating libraries can be an answer to your problem.

Another approach could be to use JSR223 (Java Scripting) for this purpose.

But in both cases, your method `fromStringToFunction()` will have a significant number of LoCs, either directly or through all the helper functions you need – not to mention the additional libraries you need to install.

You also need to specify in more detail what code sequences are allowed as the argument to `fromStringToFunction()`.

Answer (score -2):

Effectively, no. There are multiple serious problems here.

`a -> a + 1` isn't valid java. Try it:

```
class Example {
    void foo() {
        a -> a + 1; // compiler error.
        Object x = a -> a + 1; // still, compiler error.
    }
}
```

In java, all lambdas (arrow notation) and method refs (double-colon notation) **must** occur in a context where a so-called functional interface is clearly possible. Therefore, this *DOES* compile:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> f = a -> a + 1;
```

Because 'the thing on the right of the equals sign of a variable declaration that declares a variable of type `Function<Integer, Integer>`' is clearly a place where an instance of some functional interface is expected, namely: The `Function<Integer, Integer>` interface. That's why this works, vs. `Object x = ...` which doesn't, as that is NOT a functional interface, and whilst you can assign the thing `a -> a + 1` turns into, to a variable of type `Object`, the crucial aspect you seem to be missing is that the compiler will interpret `a -> a + 1` **only after** figuring out what functionalinterface you want, and therefore it is **not possible** to treat `a -> a + 1` on its own and compile it to bytecode without knowing this.

That's why what you are asking for is impossible. You're trying to first have some system 'turn `a -> a + 1` into a function, and then assign the result of that to a variable of type `Function<Integer, Integer>`, but that 'assign to a variable of type X' is a fundamental part of `a -> a + 1`: You cannot compile `a -> a + 1` without it.

Once you solve that problem this still isn't easy: The java compiler can more or less only compile entire source files (including a class declaration, and within that, a method declaration, and only within that could you write your function, which you then cannot extract from the resulting compiled bytecode...).

The common way this problem is solved is either by integrating it into the full process (so, have your build system compile this code as part of the application itself), or, by writing your dynamic code in a scripting language (not java), and then running an interpreter for this scripting language on the JVM. You can for example run JavaScript on the JVM and add a bunch of java method bridges into its equivalent of the `window` object (the global namespace). Look up 'javascript in java' or 'nashorn' for more information on this.

Comment: Thank you but the way I instantiate the function doesn't matter for me. Lambda isn't necessary, just the interface.

Comment: As you show yourself in your answer, `a -> a + 1` *is* valid Java. It just depends on where you place it in the code – as you explain yourself …

Comment: It doesn't compile. Not as a file, not as an expression. You might as well say that '+' is valid java, if you add enough stuff around it. The point is: It cannot possibly be compiled or even understood in any way or form on its own.